# What is his return on investment after one year of the job?

Tags: finance, economics

> An MBA aspirant leaves his job where he had an annual salary of $14000$ and took admission in a one-year course in a top MBA institute having fees $36000$. At the end of the course, he lands up with another job where salary is $68000$.
> a) $2.5\%$
> b) $6.25\%$
> c) $12\%$
> d) $36\%$

I tried $((\text{total profit})/(\text{investment cost}))*100=((68000-28000-36000)/(36000))*100=11.11\%$.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the cost incurs while out of work in the first year, which amounts to $50,000. Thus, the return on investment is 36%.

He is back to work the second year and there is no salary loss.

Comment: ROI=((net profit)/(Cost of investment))*100. How are you getting 36%? Can you, please explain it

Comment: $\frac{68000-50000}{50000}=\frac{18000}{50000}=36%$

Answer (score 0):

If he never went for an education, he would have an annual salary of 14 (thousand) for two years, resulting in $2 \cdot 14 = 28$ thousand.

Now that he did, the first year earned him $-36$ and the second $68$ so his total income in the second scenario is $68-36 = 32$ thousand.

Can you finish this now? (remember the profit of $32-28=4$ is over two years)

Comment: But what will be the return on investment? How should I calculate it?